# Does chessbase use a different rating system for casual games vs those for users who log in?

Tags: chessbase

when I play as a casual user the typical rating change seems to be around 25-20 points.

when I play as an official user that logs in then the ratings seem to change more in the neighborhood of 75-80 points.

So does chessbase have two different rating schemes?

Comment: This is a question for Chessbase, not for this forum.

Comment: lol, this forum is so bias.  There have been about 4-5 questions about lichess' rating system, but none were closed stating those were questions for lichess, not this forum.

Comment: To answer the OP, the K-factor determines how many rating points you gain or lose in one game.  Playchess, which is what I believe you're referring to, uses different K-factors depending on a variety of parameters (e.g. Whether a rating is provisional, the time control, etc).  Playchess does not use different rating systems (e.g. elo, URS, etc), however, they only use one rating system (i.e. elo).